# Sharing data model between UITableView and presented UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, model

I have a UITableView which modally presents a UIViewController when a cell is tapped.  The UIViewController receives data from a model object corresponding to the tapped cell, and displays an interface to edit those data.  When the user completes the edits, a button tap dismisses the UIViewController, and writes the edits to the model object.

Will the following code present any memory or design problems?

In presenting UITableView subclass implementation, acting as delegate for presented UIViewController:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
    navigationController.delegate = this;
    navigationController.dataModel = someDataModel;
}

// delegate callback
- (void) onViewControllerDone: (UIViewController *)controller {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

In presented UIViewController subclass implementation:

```
- (IBAction) done: (id)sender {
    // directly modify dataModel passed into UIViewController with data from UI
    [self.dataModel.someProperty setString: self.textView.text];

    [self.delegate onViewControllerDone:self];
}
```

Something smells funny about passing the data model into the view, and letting the view make the changes.  I'm new to Objective-C / iOS development, and not sure if there's a better/preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there isn't any flaw in what you're doing though there may be a more elegant approach to your problem. One option would be passing back the information to the original controller via delegation, so that for instance once you're done editing a certain field, the delegate is notified of this immediately and makes the required changes to the data model. This way, there's no passing of the model reference back and forth and you actually make sure that only one controller is responsible for editing it's contents. Something like:

```
- (void)doneEditing {
   if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(fieldChanged:)]) {
      [_delegate fieldChanged:self.newFieldValue];
   }
}
```